# How I can shuffle multiple JSON data in foreach? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json, shuffle

*It is not the same logic as other questions.*

---

There are two JSON data. I want to ensure that the answers to the question are written in complex form. But I couldn't do it. I can get a single JSON when I can, but I get the error when there is more than one JSON

- Questions: **The total number of people in the world?**
- Options: `{'opt1':'4 Billion','opt2':'5 Billion','opt3':'6
  Billion','opt4':'7 Billion'}`
- Answer: `{"0":"2","1":"3"}` // correct answers: 2. & 3. options
  (multiple)

**Code**

```
   $options = json_decode($quiz->options); 
   $answers = json_decode($quiz->answerOfQuestion, true);

   foreach ($options as $key => $firstvalue) {
        if (in_array(substr($key, -1), $answers)) {
        // correct options
            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".substr($key, -1)."'>";
        } else { 
        // wrong options
            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".substr($key, -1)."'>";
        }
    }
```

**What have I done?**

```
   $options = shuffle(json_decode($quiz->options)); 
   $answers = shuffle(json_decode($quiz->answerOfQuestion, true));
```

Error:

```
Unknown error type: [8] Only variables should be passed by reference
Unknown error type: [2] shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
Unknown error type: [8] Only variables should be passed by reference
Unknown error type: [2] Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How can I make the complex writing `shuffle`?

Comment: If you want to work with Arrays, you need to pass `true` as a second parameter to your json_decode function. Otherwise you'll get an object. You are doing this for answerOfQuestion but not options. Try a `var_dump()` on the results to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are fairly self-explanatory. You can't pass a value to `shuffle`, only a variable. Secondly, `shuffle` takes an array, not an object, so when you `json_decode($options)` you need to pass `true` as the second parameter to make it return an array. Note that because your `$options` is an associative array, `shuffle` won't work for you as it reindexes the array with numeric keys. Instead you can use `uasort` to shuffle it instead:

```
$answers = '{"0":"2","1":"3"}';
$answers = json_decode($answers, true);
$options = '{"opt1":"4 Billion","opt2":"5 Billion","opt3":"6 Billion","opt4":"7 Billion"}';
$options = json_decode($options, true);
uasort($options, function ($a, $b) {
    return rand(-1, 1);
});
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    if (in_array(substr($key, -1), $answers)) {
    // correct options
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".substr($key, -1)."'>" . PHP_EOL;
    } else { 
    // wrong options
        echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".substr($key, -1)."'>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output (random):

```
4 Billion<input type='checkbox' value='1'> 
5 Billion<input type='checkbox' value='2'>
7 Billion<input type='checkbox' value='4'> 
6 Billion<input type='checkbox' value='3'>
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://3v4l.org/SVeqH)